# How to use TryUpdateModel in this context?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

In my querystring I get a bunch of parameter names and values.
As I understand I should be using the built in asp.net mvc function TryUpdateModel(modelInstance).
It seems though that it is not working as I'm expecting. My parameter names do defer in capitalization. Is this a problem?
Furthermore I have some custom types that need a specific method to do some business logic checking to convert a string into an instance of this class. Where should i put this logic?

Answer (score 1):

Steve Sanderson has nearly a whole chapter on model binding in his recently published book [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework (Apress)](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/04/29/now-published-pro-aspnet-mvc-framework-apress/) which I really recommend.

Can you post some specific code that you are having trouble with?

I don't think capitalization matters, but I could be wrong.

If the DefaultModelBinder doesn't work on your complex model types, you may need to derive your own custom model binder.  Here is an extremely simplified example of a custom model binder.  I'm pretty sure the DefaultModelBinder could handle the simple Customer object defined here: [Simple custom model binder](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/09/08/CustomModelBinderMoreUIValidationASPNETMVC.aspx)

Here is another article with a few tips on model binding and building a custom model binder:  [6 Tips for ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/12788.aspx) and [Iterating on an ASP.NET MVC Model Binder](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/12801.aspx).

I still recommend the Steve Sanderson book mentioned above because it has the best explanation I've seen so far and has a more complicated example for a custom model binder (to an XDocument).